# ADFS: Error while establishing SSO Connection on windows server 2012

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, windows-server

When i access my sing-on url(https://abcd.avcd.ac/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx) from my code to establish connection with adfs, I get error as:

```
A WS-Trust endpoint that was configured could not be opened. 

Additional Data 
Address: https://win-3723jtvfe02.abcd.avcd.ac/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport 
Mode:    WindowsTransport 

Error: 
MSIS0006: A Service Principal Name is not registered for the AD FS service account.
```

And I also get warning as:

```
The SSL certificate does not contain all UPN suffix values that exist in the enterprise. 
Users with UPN suffix values not represented in the certificate will not be able to Workplace-Join their devices.
```

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the SPN issue, you'll need to get that registered. There is a nice article about that on technet here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1427.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-configure-the-spn-serviceprincipalname-for-the-service-account.aspx

If you're not using the Workplace-Join feature of ADFS 2012 R2, then you don't have to worry about that other error. If you do want to address it, though, check out the docs here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614658.aspx